# ASP.net Gridview SQL Query with multiple Tables (SQL ISSUE not ASP)

Tags: asp.net, sql

SO is Awesome learned so much!

however I have been unable to find any help on this matter wonder which genius will answer first :D

ok I have a gridview displaying results of a table as usual

however this table is one of those that store lots of ID numbers from other tables rather then the name of the item. ie

(tbluser)         (tblreg)        (tblact)     (tblsite)     (tblsite)
Fname----sname----regionaccess----accountaccess----basedloc----currentsite----active
test-----test----------1----------------1--------------1-------------1---------true

so the numbers are the ID numbers in other tables that I can reference too, however this makes no sense on the gridview display to anyone who reads it.

so I need a Sql Select Statement which connects (or joins I think is the right word) to the appropriate tables and get the name for each of the id numbers so that the Gridview looks like

Fname----sname----regionaccess----accountaccess----basedloc----currentsite----active
test-----test---------Admin ---------AccessAll-------T'Ton--------T'Ton-------true

Can Anyone help?

Edit:
Here is the SQL that (semi) worked, had to change to inner joins as VS wouldn't accept it,

SELECT Users.[First Name], Users.Surname, Users.Login, Regions.RegionName, [Profile Options].ProfileDesc, Sites.Sitename AS OwningSite, Sites.Sitename AS SiteSetting
FROM (Sites INNER JOIN (Regions INNER JOIN Users ON Regions.RegionID = Users.[Region Access]) ON (Sites.SiteID = Users.owningsite) AND (Regions.RegionID = Sites.owningregionid) AND (Sites.SiteID = Users.Currentsitesetting)) INNER JOIN [Profile Options] ON Users.[Account Access] = [Profile Options].ProfileID

problem is it gathers the names from the other tables Great, but doesn't display all the records in users table only ones with the same IDs where its getting the names from

Comment: Apologies the table formats didn't keep, the first two field are fine from tbluser, the four ID numbers come from the other 4 tables.

Comment: How do you get the data from the database - SqlDataSource? SqlCommand? Post the relevant code so you can get exactly the help you need.

Comment: Through Access Select Command, but would that really change the SQL? surely how the SQL is called doesn't affect the statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to join the tables in you selectcommand as you said. This worked for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbluser.Fname as Firstname,
    tbluser.sname as Username (? or something)
    tblreg.? as ?
    <tablename>.<columnname> as <some custom name>
    ...
    (only select the things you want to display in the grid ofc.)

FROM tableWithIds
    LEFT JOIN tbluser
        ON tableWithIds.userid = tbluser.userid
    LEFT JOIN tblreg
        ON tableWithIds.someid = tblreg.someid
    LEFT JOIN <someothertable>
        ON tableWithIds.someid = someothertable.otherid
    ...
    (join all the tables by id)
```

The left join makes sure you will get all the results from the tablewithids even if the remoteid is not present. If you only want results if the remote id (the userid for example) is there, change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN for the desired table.
The SELECT DISTINCT makes sure you wont get any duplicate values from all the joins. If you only want to distinct a few colums (because a user can have multiple sites for example) use this: select distinct username, lastname, ... from (select (the rest) from table)

Is this what you are looking for?